# play2 - ebean - named query user was not found for models.Investigation

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm trying to externalise my raw sql queries by putting them into the orm.xml config file.

I'm encountering the error:

`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: named query user was not found for models.Investigation`

In play2, ebean is enabled. I've added the `orm.xml` to the conf directory (and I can see it's been found in the classpath).

Application.conf:

`ebean.default="models.*"`

Extract from `orm.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings>
    <entity class="models.Investigation">
        <raw-sql name="user">
            <columnMapping column="id" property="id" />
            <columnMapping column="title" property="title" />
            <columnMapping column="code" property="code" />
            <query>
            QUERY HERE
            </query>
        </raw-sql>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

My `Investigation` class is just a standard bean annotated with `@Sql` and `@Entity`

Controller code:

```
List<Investigation> investigations = Ebean.createNamedQuery(Investigation.class, "user").findList();
```

The named query is never found. Any idea what it could be? I've googled around for the past couple of hours but to no avail.